# Backup files in pre-folders of a certain size

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, backup

I want to backup my NAS on multiple DVD's. What i had in mind was a script what does the following:

-Create a folder for each DVD
-Copy the files and filestructure into the DVD folders
-Stop / goto next DVD folder when the first DVD folder is full

i.e. the trigger is 4 GByte (which calculates easy for the example)

I have a datasrouce with 10 gb of data., so this will be 3 DVD's. So the script first create three folders: DVD-1, DVD-2 and DVD-3. Next the copy will start to copy 4 GB to the DVD-1 folder. After that, the remaining files must come in DVD-2 and DVD-3.

As far as i know, rsync and cp doesn't bother about calculating this. I know it is an option to do this by using archives like zip, tar or gz but at first i want to try it with unpacked files.

Is all above an option with standard Linux bash commands or is it insane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any standard tool that does this out of the box. But it's pretty simple to code up, and there are a few projects to do it:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18628/generating-sets-of-files-that-fit-on-a-given-media-size-for-tar-t